# ORDER BY with UNION in each query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, union

I have a query with `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Test WHERE Username LIKE '%me%'
AND DateTime > '2015-12-03' AND DateTime < '2015-12-04' ORDER BY DateTime ACS
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Test WHERE Username LIKE '%me%' 
AND DateTime > '2015-12-03' AND DateTime < '2015-12-04' ORDER BY DateTime DESC
```

But this query is giving me error in `UNION`.

How can I resolve it?

EDIT
Sorry, forgot to say that I want to SELECT the First and the Last data from one day

Comment: don't worry about the caps, its just a habit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `ORDER BY` on `UNION` on the last query. To achieve your desired output:

> SELECT the First and the Last data from one day

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTime ASC),
        rn2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
    FROM Test 
    WHERE
        Username LIKE '%me%' 
        AND DateTime > '2015-12-03' 
        AND DateTime < '2015-12-04'
)
SELECT * FROM Cte WHERE rn1 = 1 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Cte WHERE rn2 = 1
```

You can also simplify this by using `OR` instead of `UNION ALL`:

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTime ASC),
        rn2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
    FROM Test 
    WHERE
        Username LIKE '%me%' 
        AND DateTime > '2015-12-03' 
        AND DateTime < '2015-12-04'
)
SELECT * FROM Cte WHERE rn1 = 1 OR rn2 = 1
```

But the result will be different if the first and last data is the same. The first query will return 2 identical rows while the second will only return 1 row.

Comment: I prefer the first query, because I need that 2 rows